# How rotate rectangle around corner on applet?

Tags: java, animation, graphics, awt, java-2d

I want to rotate the rectangle around one of corner, but I don't now how determine the new coordinates of corners. Rotation may be around any corner.
May be exists another method of rotation?

Can someone help me?

[screenshot of my applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dNau.png)

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainApplet extends Applet implements Runnable {

int width, height;
int i = 0;
Thread t = null;
boolean threadSuspended;

public void init() {
    width = getSize().width;
    height = getSize().height;
    setBackground(Color.black);
}

public void destroy() {}


public void start() {
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread(this);
        threadSuspended = false;
        t.start();
    } else {
        if (threadSuspended) {
            threadSuspended = false;
            synchronized (this) {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void stop() {
    threadSuspended = true;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            ++i;
            if (i == 359) {
                i = 0;
            }
            showStatus("i is " + i);

            if (threadSuspended) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (threadSuspended) {
                        wait();
                    }
                }
            }
            repaint();
            t.sleep(100);  // interval given in milliseconds
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.green);

    g.drawRect(200,150, (int) (50*Math.cos(i)-100*Math.sin(i)+200-200*Math.cos(i)+150*Math.sin(i)),
                        (int) (50*Math.sin(i)+100*Math.cos(i)+150-200*Math.sin(i)-150*Math.cos(i)));
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: It was task from teacher.

Comment: *"It was task from teacher."* OK. Give them that link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Graphics2D`'s `.rotate(theta, double x, double y)` method.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
  //Create Graphics2D object:
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

  //Create rectangle of origin (0,0), w=30, h=50
  Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
  rectangle.setBounds(0,0,30,50);

  //Rotate rectangle by 1 radian(Math.PI) from the bottom corner
  g2d.rotate(Math.PI, rectangle.x + rectangle.width/2, rectangle.y + rectangle.height/2);

  //Draw rectangle
  g2d.draw(rectangle);
}
```

Comment: @Sergo I added comments to explain how this works. If you replace your "paint" method with the one I wrote, then you will see that the rectangle can rotate. Keep in mind ".rotate(theta, x, y)" theta is in radians, not degrees.

Comment: I replaced, but he don't move. Do you made another changes?

Comment: public void paint(Graphics g){   
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
   g2d.setColor(Color.green);     

   Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();      
   rectangle.setBounds(100,100,50,70);

   g2d.rotate(Math.PI*0.00555*i, rectangle.x, rectangle.y);    

   g2d.draw(rectangle);
 }  //and change sleep(10)

Comment: Thankyou for help
:)